# Python serial - Conflict between Serial Over Bluetooth link and USB serial device comport + Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, pyserial

I'm currently writing a python script to connect to a USB device via serial and I'm having some trouble with it. Python serial cannot connect to my device (which uses COM6 (USB)), because python serial is trying to open a connection with the Another COM6 from my computer (from a non-connected Bluetooth Device). How they can have the same port number is beyond my mind, but that happens on Windows 10.

My question is: What is the difference between the two COM ports and how to "force" python serial to open the USB one.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You have to fix the issue with the two ports named COM6 on Windows level.

Comment: Can it be automated or something?

Comment: Fixing Windows? I doubt that.

Comment: You could try: unplug the COM6 USB serial adapter, uninstall it in Device manager (you will probably have to select View->Show Hidden Devices to see it to delete) , then plug it in again.

Comment: If I remove the bluetooth devices manually, it works, but I really need it to be automated or something.